# Android Spring 1.0.1 Delete with Basic Authentication

Tags: java, android, spring

I am using Android Spring 1.0.1.([API-docs-here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html?overview-tree.html))

I have GET and POST(adding an object) transactions working with basic Authentication but how do I do a delete?

Get and post look like this:

`RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(createHeaders(login, password));
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(url.toString(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, objectClassToDownload);`

...and...

`RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Http httpEntity = new HttpEntity(objectToAdd, createHeaders(login, password));
Object resultObject = restTemplate.postForObject(url.toString(), httpEntity, objectToAdd.getClass());`

There are delete(...) methods in RestTemplate but I can't see how to incorporate Basic Authentication into them.
Then there are the exchange... and execute... methods, I've tried an exchange one but it doesn't work (I can add the details but maybe exchange is not the right approach?)

Has anyone got a delete example in this context?

Thanks, much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use HTTP GET but with a command that says delete**

In other words, don't even try HTTP Delete.  Instead use HTTP GET as above but with something in the URL that says delete, e.g.

`http://mywebservice/myObjects/31`  to retrieve object 31 and

`http://mywebservice/myObjects/31/delete` to delete it.  Both are HTTP GET commands.

That doesn't exactly answer the question but maybe that's how everyone gets around this problem?

Comment: Well... nothing better has come along so far so this, for now, is the right answer.